# Как вывести лог ядра Linux в UART в QEMU?

Tags: linux, ядро, qemu

Я запускаю ядро Linux так:

```
 ~ $ qemu-system-i386 -k en-gb -m 8G -smp cpus=6 -kernel ./bzImage-5.10-184 -initrd ./initrd -accel kvm -append 'boot_delay=100'
```

Без параметра *boot_delay* у меня загрузка останавливается через 1.6 секунд (сам параметр я применяю, чтобы хоть как-то развидеть лог ядра). Но дело в том, что ядро в какой-то момент ломает фреймбуфер, из-за чего пропадает важный кусок dmesg - тот, в котором выскакивает "Call Trace:", который представляет собой информацию об ошибке в драйвере. Я вижу лишь его обрывок, причём в конце. И этот обрывок говорит о том, что ошибка в каком-то драйвере на AMD, но в каком именно - я понятия не имею. Т е, я вижу что-то такое:

```
[   3.257577]  ? init_amd+097b/0xa10
[   3.257577]  ? report_bug+0x94/0xd0
...
[   3.257577] ---[ end trace 15543f21cc7c6b0c ] ---
[ 113.810033] kvm-guest: steal time: CPU 1, msr 34a84c40
```

Но я хочу увидеть начало Call Trace, чтобы знать, в каком конкретно драйвере проблема, обычно там пишется что-то типа:

```
Error at drivers/rtl8192eu/rtl8192eu.c:
```

Вопрос: как с QEMU эмулировать UART и вывести весь лог ядра "в лоб" именно туда, а не в ломающийся фреймбуфер? Ну и да, 5.10.184 ядро не поддерживает pstore_blk, да и на ядре 5.15 у меня такое не прокатило, хоть такое в то ядро было включено...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было запускать так:

```
 ~ $ qemu-system-i386 -kernel ./bzImage-5.10-184 -initrd ./initrd -k en-gb -m 8G -smp cpus=6 -accel kvm -append 'console=ttyS0' -serial stdio
```

`'console=ttyS0'` перенаправляет лог ядра в UART, а `-serial stdio` выводит этот лог прямо в терминал.